# Update Related Models When Deleting DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I have a model that can be deleted in my app - **Project User** I want when the model is deleted every other Model that relates to it must be updated to a system user - so update all the references to this Project User to another user. Is that possible?

Comment: So you have two models? Can you share the models? Do they share al/most) fields?

Comment: I have one model - **Project User** all the other models have project_user as a field that links to a **Project User**. Let me know if I'm making sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model is foreign keyed to the user, you're looking for the on_delete property of the foreign key, use models.SET()

See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/ 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/models/deletion/#SET

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you define a field in a model if its a foreign key. do add

```
class some_model(models.Model):

    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```